# setting up if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))

Tags: php, sql-server, email

I am running a simply insert form and checking for errors. When I try to put `if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))` in my if statement, it loads a blank white page no matter what. Is this not set up on my server? How would I do that if that's the case.

Here is the context I am trying to use it:

```
if(empty($_POST['email']) && !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
```

thanks

Comment: Make sure you are running php 5.2 or greater

Comment: Run `phpinfo()` per John Conde's comment. And check your error logs.

Comment: Blank white page? Make sure you've turned on error reporting. Add `ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of your script.

Comment: I gave you a perfectly good (and tested) answer in your other question but you decided to accept the other one instead. Your problem is in your DB, not the form. I deleted my answer btw, no sense in me putting any more effort into what I already spent.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Your answer worked but the other answer was more suitable for my needs. Thanks for your time. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user2684452 If it "worked" then, then the honorable thing to have done, is, you should've upvoted it then. I don't mind helping, but I don't like it when I feel I've wasted my time.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: Vote Up requires at least 15 rep and the user has only 3. Maybe they didn't know how to accept the answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- totally understandable. I am unable to upvote currently. The other use spent time as well, and happened to have a more suitable answer. I guess that's the downside to the voting system?

Comment: Replace `&&` with `||`, btw.